# Access tokens created by /oauth2/authorize failed to get claims in secondary user store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

If I create an access token with **/oauth2/token** endpoint, the scope openid works perfectly using the secondary user store, but when created an access token with **/oauth2/authorize**, the scope openid don't work in the secondary user store, when I use the **/userinfo?schema=openid**, the response is empty, is this a bug or this behavior is expected? Because in the PRIMARY user store, works perfectly. If the user is created in the PRIMARY user store, the **/oauth2/authorize** endpoint works correctly.

I try the authorize endpoint, using authorization code or implicit, the result is the same.

**EDITED**: The claim management was configured to get information in the secondary user store, like this: **http://wso2.com/claims/emailaddress** is mapped to **mail;JDBC/email**, and in the **http://wso2.com/oidc/claim**, emailaddress also mapped to **mail;JDBC/email**.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the JWT toke string that returns?

Comment: Dear Thusitha, yes, the JWT also is empty, but your question, is very good to explain the problem, both userinfo api and JWT are empty when user store is a secondary. Thank you.

Comment: I have recently tried same sort of scenario using IS 5.0.0 and playground2 app and a secondary user store. As far as I remember it worked without any issue. If i get time I'll check and get back to you. Are you using Oauth2TokenValidation service?

Comment: No, I'm not using Oauth2TokenValidation service, well, at least I don't remember configure that.

Comment: Thusitha, do you had time to look this problem? I can't solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't. can you send email with your steps to dev@wso2.org